# get(position) shows on a null references

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

So, I have two recyclerview with their different adapter. I want to display one of them if I click a button. The other adapter works well. But not with the second adapter.

**body**

```
09-07 21:41:37.000 11177-11219/com.example.android.footballmatchschedule I/System.out: {"events":[{"idEvent":"576511","idSoccerXML":"389896","strEvent":"Huddersfield Town vs Crystal Palace","strFilename":"English Premier League 2018-09-15 Huddersfield Town vs Crystal Palace","strSport":"Soccer","idLeague":"4328","strLeague":"English Premier League","strSeason":"1819","strDescriptionEN":null,"strHomeTeam":"Huddersfield Town","strAwayTeam":"Crystal Palace","intHomeScore":null,"intRound":"5","intAwayScore":null,"intSpectators":null,"strHomeGoalDetails":null,"strHomeRedCards":null,"strHomeYellowCards":null,"strHomeLineupGoalkeeper":null,"strHomeLineupDefense":null,"strHomeLineupMidfield":null,"strHomeLineupForward":null,"strHomeLineupSubstitutes":null,"strHomeFormation":null,"strAwayRedCards":null,"strAwayYellowCards":null,"strAwayGoalDetails":null,"strAwayLineupGoalkeeper":null,"strAwayLineupDefense":null,"strAwayLineupMidfield":null,"strAwayLineupForward":null,"strAwayLineupSubstitutes":null,"strAwayFormation":null,"intHomeShots":null,"intAwayShots":null,"dateEvent":"2018-09-15","strDate":"15\/09\/18","strTime":"14:00:00+00:00","strTVStation":null,"idHomeTeam":"133932","idAwayTeam":"133632","strResult":null,"strCircuit":null,"strCountry":null,"strCity":null,"strPoster":null,"strFanart":null,"strThumb":null,"strBanner":null,"strMap":null,"strLocked":"unlocked"},{"idEvent":"576512","idSoccerXML":"389897","strEvent":"Man City vs Fulham","strFilename":"English Premier League 2018-09-15 Man City vs Fulham","strSport":"Soccer","idLeague":"4328","strLeague":"English Premier League","strSeason":"1819","strDescriptionEN":null,"strHomeTeam":"Man City","strAwayTeam":"Fulham","intHomeScore":null,"intRound":"5","intAwayScore":null,"intSpectators":null,"strHomeGoalDetails":null,"strHomeRedCards":null,"strHomeYellowCards":null,"strHomeLineupGoalkeeper":null,"strHomeLineupDefense":null,"strHomeLineupMidfield":null,"strHomeLineupForward":null,"strHomeLineupSubstitutes":null,"strHomeFormation":null,"strAwayRedCards":null,"strAwayYellowCards":null,"strAwayGoalDetails":null,"strAwayLineupGoalkeeper":null,"strAwayLineupDefense":null,"strAwayLineupMidfield":null,"strAwayLineupForward":null,"strAwayLineupSubstitutes":null,"strAwayFormation":null,"intHomeShots":null,"intAwayShots":null,"dateEvent":"2018-09-15","strDate":"15\/09\/18","strTime":"14:00:00+00:00","strTVStation":null,"idHomeTeam":"133613","idAwayTeam":"133600","strResult":null,"strCircuit":null,"strCountry":null,"strCity":null,"strPoster":null,"strFanart":null,"strThumb":null,"strBanner":null,"strMap":null,"strLocked":"unlocked"},{"idEvent":"576513","idSoccerXML":"389898","strEvent":"Newcastle vs Arsenal","strFilename":"English Premier League 2018-09-15 Newcastle vs Arsenal","strSport":"Soccer","idLeague":"4328","strLeague":"English Premier League","strSeason":"1819","strDescriptionEN":null,"strHomeTeam":"Newcastle","strAwayTeam":"Arsenal","intHomeScore":null,"intRound":"5","intAwayScore":null,"intSpectators":null,"strHomeGoalDetails":null,"strHomeRedCards":null,"strHomeYellowCards":null,"strHomeLineupGoalkeeper":null,"strHomeLineupDefense":null,"strHomeLineupMidfield":null,"strHomeLineupForward":null,"strHomeLineupSubstitutes":null,"strHomeFormation":null,"strAwayRedCards":null,"strAwayYellowCards":null,"strAwayGoalDetails":null,"strAwayLineupGoalkeeper":null,"strAwayLineupDefense":null,"strAwayLineupMidfield":null,"strAwayLineupForward":null,"strAwayLineupSubstitutes":null,"strAwayFormation":null,"intHomeShots":null,"intAwayShots":null,"dateEvent":"2018-09-15","strDate":"15\/09\/18","strTime":"14:00:00+00:00","strTVStation":null,"idHomeTeam":"134777","idAwayTeam":"133604","strResult":null,"strCircuit":null,"strCountry":null,"strCity":null,"strPoster":null,"strFanart":null,"strThumb":null,"strBanner":null,"strMap":null,"strLocked":"unlocked"},{"idEvent":"576515","idSoccerXML":"389900","strEvent":"Bournemouth vs Leicester","strFilename":"English Premier League 2018-09-15 Bournemouth vs Leicester","strSport":"Soccer","idLeague":"4328","strLeague":"English Premier League","strSeason":"1819","strDescriptionEN":null,"strHomeTeam":"Bournemout
```

**NextMatch class**

```
class NextMatch(val event: List<Event>)
class Event(val strDate: String, val strHomeTeam: String, val strAwayTeam: String)
```

**fetchJson function**

```
fun fetchJson(){
    //Json for prev match
    val url = "https://www.thesportsdb.com/api/v1/json/1/eventspastleague.php?id=4328"
    val url2 = "https://www.thesportsdb.com/api/v1/json/1/eventsnextleague.php?id=4328"
    val request = Request.Builder().url(url).build()
    val request2 = Request.Builder().url(url2).build()
    val client = OkHttpClient()
    client.newCall(request).enqueue(object: Callback{
        override fun onResponse(call: Call?, response: Response?){
            println("sukses")
            val body = response?.body()?.string()
            println(body)

            val gson = GsonBuilder().create()

            val prevMatch = gson.fromJson(body, PrevMatch::class.java)

            runOnUiThread { recyclerView_prevMatch.adapter = MainAdapters(prevMatch) }
        }
        override fun onFailure(call: Call?, e: IOException?){
            println("failed request")
        }
    })
    client.newCall(request2).enqueue(object: Callback{
        override fun onResponse(call: Call?, response: Response?){
            println("sukses")
            val body = response?.body()?.string()
            println(body)

            val gson = GsonBuilder().create()

            val nextMatch = gson.fromJson(body, NextMatch::class.java)

            runOnUiThread { recyclerView_nextMatch.adapter = MainAdapter(nextMatch) }
        }
        override fun onFailure(call: Call?, e: IOException?){
            println("failed request")
        }
    })
```

**MainAdapter.kt** file:

```
class MainAdapter(val nextMatch: NextMatch): RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomViewHolder>(){

//Adapter Next Match

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return 15
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CustomViewHolder {
    val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
    val callForRow = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_row,parent,false)
    return CustomViewHolder(callForRow)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CustomViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.view.team_home.text =  nextMatch.event.get(position).strHomeTeam
    holder.view.team_away.text =  nextMatch.event.get(position).strAwayTeam
    holder.view.time_schedule.text = nextMatch.event.get(position).strDate
}

}
```

And when I tried to run it, it force stopped. After I look at the Logcat:

```
Process: com.example.android.footballmatchschedule, PID: 8307
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.List.get(int)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.android.footballmatchschedule.MainAdapter.onBindViewHolder(MainAdapter.kt:24)
    at com.example.android.footballmatchschedule.MainAdapter.onBindViewHolder(MainAdapter.kt:9)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6673)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6714)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5647)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5913)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5752)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5748)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2232)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1559)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1519)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:614)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3812)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3225)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19147)
    at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.internalMeasureChildren(ConstraintLayout.java:1212)
    at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1552)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19147)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6113)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:223)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:141)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19147)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6113)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:400)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19147)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6113)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:223)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19147)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6113)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1723)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:788)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:648)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19147)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6113)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:223)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:3346)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19147)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2491)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1450)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1704)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1323)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6718)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:894)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:696)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:631)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:880)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5737)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller
```

It shows that the get(position) function from API trying to get it from a null object. How can it be? I mean how can I solve this?

Comment: Check that `nextMatch.event` isn't null before running your code in `onBindViewHolder`

Comment: Be careful with deleting post, you don't want to end up with a post ban. https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans

Comment: Okay.. my bad. I don't know about this and you're telling me about this. thank you very much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @RayhanHanaputra you're welcome. that's why I mentioned it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suspect your `NextMatch` is a java defined type, where the `event` could be null. 
Try change on `onBindViewHolder` function to below

```
fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CustomViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val event = nextMatch.event
    if (event != null) {
        holder.view.team_home.text = event.get(position).strHomeTeam
        holder.view.team_away.text = event.get(position).strAwayTeam
        holder.view.time_schedule.text = event.get(position).strDate
    } else {
        Log.d("TAG", "event is null!!")
    }
}
```

If you see the log `event is null`, it's confirm you need to set your `event` in the `nextMatch` object first, before using it.

**UPDATED**

Per the additional shared information, the issue is due to the `event` variable of `NextMatch` mis-match with the body JSON name `events`.

So to fix, just change the

```
class NextMatch(val event: List<Event>)
```

to

```
class NextMatch(val events: List<Event>)
```

Then the gson deserialization will work, where `events` now is no longer null.

Comment: yes i see that logs. Is there something wrong with my fetch Json function from the API?

Comment: Probably. So it's nothing wrong with this recycler view, or the adapter. The place where it is wrong is the setup of your `nextMatch` variable.

Comment: I have added the function to my post. I don't think if there is something wrong with them

Comment: Can you provide what's in `body` and what's the format of `NextMatch` looks like?

Comment: Found the issue, and propose the solution, change your `event` to `events` instead

Comment: If this answer your question, and helped, do upvote this answer, and tick it ya :) Thanks.

Comment: Solved! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Your RecyclerView adapter's item count is constant, are you sure for this?

```
override fun getItemCount(): Int {
     return 15
}
```

Comment: Oh yeah. my bad. I could use nextMatch.events.count() instead. thanks for your reminder. really appreciate this.

Comment: In my opinion Mete is correct. This is the true root to the issue the OP is experiencing. No need to check for `null` when  `getItemCount()` returns the correct value!